# How to set up a PPPoE connection on a router which connects to the Internet through another router

Tags: configuration, pppoe, bridge-router

My ISP has given me a router on which I **don't have permission to set up the configuration** (well, the important part at least. It's in ***bridge mode***, ISP says). To connect to the Internet, I have to create a **PPPoE connection on my computer**.

I want to connect another router which only handles this PPPoE connection -- **how can I make it hand everything else to the router in *bridge mode*?**

I have to turn off DHCP, right? What about DNS, NAT and other settings?

*(Asked on **[superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/562593/how-to-set-up-a-pppoe-connection-on-a-router-which-connects-to-the-internet-thro)**, but no one seems to be able to help there.)*

Comment: You should contact your ISP for assistance. As it stands there's not enough information here for anyone to give you a decent answer. Also, please familiarize yourself with the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq).

Answer (score 1):

If the router in front is in bridge mode, it's like you have an enthernet cable between you and the ISP, so you just need to configure your router's WAN interface to make the PPPoE connection. Most SoHo routers will disable the unnecessary services when you select the "connect with PPPoE" option. If you give a router model, people can probably explain everything that needs to be configured in more detail.